# toggleClass not working as expected inside an each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple navigation with dropdowns. The only issue that I am having is that when a click on a link that has a down arrow icon(like link1 link2 link3) it doesn't rotate when clicking on another link that has a down arrow icon. I am not sure why this is happening. Please help me. Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.dropdown').each(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-toggle", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(".dropdown-toggle i", $dropdown).toggleClass('rotate-arrow');

      $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu", $dropdown);

      $dropdownMenu.toggle();

      $(".dropdown-menu").not($dropdownMenu).hide();
    });

  });


});
```

```css
.rotate-arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.show-dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 1 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 1 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 1 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 2 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 3 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you really complicate your life ...! There is simpler to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't rotate when clicking on another link

Because you don't have any code to remove the `rotate-arrow` class - add:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle i").removeClass("rotate-arrow");
```

or, more specifically, to keep the same format as your menu toggle:

```
  var $dropdowntoggle = $(".dropdown-toggle i", $dropdown)
  $dropdowntoggle.toggleClass('rotate-arrow');
  $(".dropdown-toggle i").not($dropdowntoggle).removeClass("rotate-arrow");
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.dropdown').each(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $("a.dropdown-toggle", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      var $dropdowntoggle = $(".dropdown-toggle i", $dropdown)
      $dropdowntoggle.toggleClass('rotate-arrow');
      $(".dropdown-toggle i").not($dropdowntoggle).removeClass("rotate-arrow");

      var $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu", $dropdown);
      $dropdownMenu.toggle();
      $(".dropdown-menu").not($dropdownMenu).hide();
    });

  });


});
```

```css
.rotate-arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.show-dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 1 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 1 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 1 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 2 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 2 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="expanded dropdown">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 3 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3 inner 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">link 3 inner 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

bad method !
CSS means **Cascading** Style Sheets

```js
$('.dropdown a').click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let $_LI = $(this).closest('li');

  if (!$_LI.hasClass('selected')) {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  }
  $_LI.toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
nav ul { list-style: none;}

li > ul { display: none; }
li.selected > a > i { transform: rotate(180deg); }
li.selected > ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="menu nav">
    <li class="expanded dropdown">
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 1 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 1 inner 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 1 inner 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded dropdown">
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 2 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 2 inner 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 2 inner 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded dropdown">
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Link 3 <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="menu dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 3 inner 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link 3 inner 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```